# How it can be done in Mirth? I want to define a custom HL7 V2 (2.4) schema rather the default and to validate the incoming V2 messages

Tags: mirth

I want to define a custom HL7 V2 (2.4) schema rather the default and to validate the incoming V2 messages based on my custom schema defined.

i) The input message would be

MSH|^~&|Hey|Hey|Pharmacy|RE1267|20220717072035||ADT^A04^ADT_A05|20220720092046|P|2.4|||NE|NE|MYS||||
EVN||20220720092034
PID|1|MRN_X01|983103^^^^AD011||Mohamed^Fatimah^Noor^^NP003^^US004||19901021162034|FEMALE

ii) The user defined schema would be

[image]
But, I'm not sure how it can be achieved in Mirth.

My question is that does Mirth allow to define custom HL7 message and so parse the input?

If it is possible then could anyone explain how it can be done pls ?

Note: I've attached a sample xsd (pls consider it as sample alone) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the code that I have used in my JavaScript(Postprocessor) for a customized dynamic response message.

In source->Source Settings-> Responnse->Select PostProcesor.

> Script: //Here is the customized HL7MESSAGE.

```
var msg = <HL7Message/>;
var time = DateUtil.getCurrentDate('yyyyMMddHHmmss');
var messageControllerID = globalMap.get('controllerID');

createSegment('MSH',msg);
msg.MSH['MSH.1']='|';
msg.MSH['MSH.2']='^~\&';
msg.MSH['MSH.3']['MSH.3.1']='PACS_APP';
msg.MSH['MSH.4']['MSH.4.1']='PACS_FACILITY';
msg.MSH['MSH.5']['MSH.5.1']='HIS_APP';
msg.MSH['MSH.6']['MSH.6.1']='HIS_FACILITY';
msg.MSH['MSH.7']['MSH.7.1']=time;
msg.MSH['MSH.8']['MSH.8.1']='';
msg.MSH['MSH.9']['MSH.9.1']='ACK';
msg.MSH['MSH.10']['MSH.10.1']=messageControllerID;
msg.MSH['MSH.11']['MSH.11.1']='P';
msg.MSH['MSH.12']['MSH.12.1']='2.3';
msg.MSH['MSH.13']['MSH.13.1']='1';
msg.MSH['MSH.14']['MSH.14.1']='';
msg.MSH['MSH.15']['MSH.15.1']='';
msg.MSH['MSH.16']['MSH.16.1']='';
msg.MSH['MSH.17']['MSH.17.1']='91';
msg.MSH['MSH.18']['MSH.18.1']='';
msg.MSH['MSH.19']['MSH.19.1']='';
msg.MSH['MSH.20']['MSH.20.1']='';


createSegment('MSA',msg);
msg.MSA['MSA.1']['MSA.1.1']='AA';
msg.MSA['MSA.2']['MSA.2.1']=messageControllerID;
msg.MSA['MSA.3']['MSA.3.1']='Order Registered.';
msg.MSA['MSA.4']['MSA.4.1']='';
msg.MSA['MSA.5']['MSA.5.1']='';
msg.MSA['MSA.6']['MSA.6.1']='';

var messages=SerializerFactory.getSerializer('HL7V2').fromXML(msg)
return messages;
```

Comment: Thank you Shanmathi for the reply. But you did not understand the question that raised. Your answer to the question is wrong. Actually I'm talking about inbound scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Put the HL7 message above in the inbound message template of the source connector and put the content of the user defined validation schema as global map variables that will be referenced whilst you parse every HL7 message.